# Dotenv configuration isn't working with React.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I have a React app working with Webpack and Babel, I'm trying to load the `.env` constants in my react components using **process.env** but this object is always empty. It looks like there is `dotenv` plugin running in the background, but it's not working with my project.

I expect to see the .env(located at the root of the app) constants  inside my react components.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "**************",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.3",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev":   "webpack -d --watch",
    "test":  "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'file'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default)
            safe: false // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe)
        })
    ]
};
```

I tried following:

1. [Adding Development Environment Variables In .env](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) — didn't work.
2. [DotenvPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#dotenvplugin) — didn't work.
3. [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx) — I managed to load constants using DefinePlugin from webpack conf but I really need to be able to use `.env` files instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: You isn't using ejected app so I recommend you to use `react-app-env` instead.

Comment: I was searching about this question and your option 1 it works in my ejected react app using dotenv.

Answer (score 3):

One issue may be that create-react-app by default will ignore any .env variables that aren't prefixed with 'REACT_APP_'

There is a section in the create-react-app read me [Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) that explains this in more detail

Their reasoning behind it is so you can't unintentionally include environment variables from other projects on your system